# Is it possible to install two Android APKs but only show one on the launcher?

Tags: android, mobile, apk

I'm currently looking at a problem where we need to move from having two separate Android apps that a user must install to an approach where the user installs only one, but during their initial setup, we essentially "boot" into one or the other.

Short of merging the codebases of these two apps together, I would have thought it would be possible to somehow download one APK on-the-fly as required, like a plug-in. From some reading though it seems like this will involve another icon being added to the user's Android launcher, which may (debateably) prove confusing for them.

Is there a way to avoid this happening? Or is this just the wrong way to approach this problem altogether?

Comment: But why you want to install two apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove following lines from AndroidMenifest.xml file which icon you dont want to show on Launcher screen,

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This is the line which creates icon on Launcher. If you want to Launch some activity then use Intent for startactivity().

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, hide the launcher icon, but then essentially launch MainActivityAppA or MainActivityAppB depending on whether A or B is selected in the up-front choice?

Does that essentially mean it's possible to publish an APK to the Android app store that doesn't result in a launcher icon getting created under applications? (Perhaps that's how google frameworky stuff already works, I'm not particularly familiar with it)